# issues loading Milan stock exchange etfs data with yahoo

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm experiencing some issue in downloading data from Yahoo finance

```
library(quantmod)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(roll)

tickers = c('eue.mi', 'iusa.mi')
price_data <- tq_get(tickers, get = "stock.prices", from = " 2021-05-01", to = "2021-10-31")



price_data <- na.omit(price_data) 

price_data <- price_data[,c(1,2,8)]
names(price_data)[3] <- "adjClose"
```

The problem arises when I try to  download data for all etf tickers (they're about one thousand).
Please note that in the past months I've performed this operation without problems.
Now I get an empty table and a lot of warnings of two main types:

```
48: Problem with `mutate()` input `data..`.
i x = 's2eubh.mi', get = 'stock.prices': Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "s2eubh.mi", env = <environment>, : Unable to import “s2eubh.mi”.
l'argomento "conn"  non è specificato e non ha un valore predefinito
 Removing s2eubh.mi.
i Input `data..` is `purrr::map(...)`.
49: In for (i in seq_along(specs)) { ... :
  closing unused connection 8 (https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/s2eubh.mi?period1=1609459200&period2=1635638400&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=2ywnPZPXRi6)
```

What I can do in order to avoid this issue?
I have several etf rotation strategies running and I need once a month to download data of the last 6 month of nearly every etf ticker on that stock exchange.
Here You can find a complete tickers list:

```
'eue.mi', 'eun.mi', 'mse.mi', 'dje.mi', 'iusa.mi', 'eqqq.mi', 'mgt.mi', 'etfmib.mi', 'ibcx.mi', 'ijpn.mi', 'fxc.mi', 'djmc.mi', 'djsc.mi', 'jpn.mi', 'idvy.mi', 
'iprp.mi', 'isf.mi', 'meu.mi', 'ifff.mi', 'ibzl.mi', 'ieem.mi', 'ikor.mi', 'itwn.mi', 'iwrd.mi', 'ibci.mi', 'lqde.mi', 'iukd.mi', 'lusa.mi', 'wld.mi', 'iapd.mi', 
'inaa.mi', 'ieux.mi', 'ibts.mi', 'ibgs.mi', 'daxx.mi', 'daxlev.mi', 'indi.mi', 'grc.mi', 'emkt.mi', 'xsmi.mi', 'xmib.mi', 'xesx.mi', 'xmus.mi', 'xmjp.mi', 
'xmeu.mi', 'xmwo.mi', 'ibtm.mi', 'ibgx.mi', 'ibgm.mi', 'ibgl.mi', 'itps.mi', 'iasp.mi', 'iwdp.mi', 'iusp.mi', 'infr.mi', 'itky.mi', 'iglt.mi', 'xmem.mi', 'xmas.mi', 
'xmla.mi', 'xmea.mi', 'xmtw.mi', 'xmbr.mi', 'xnif.mi', 'xmko.mi', 'xx25.mi', 'xd3e.mi', 'xgsd.mi', 'xspr.mi', 'xser.mi', 'xsdr.mi', 'xsr.mi', 'xskr.mi', 'xs8r.mi', 
'xs6r.mi', 'xs3r.mi', 'xsnr.mi', 'xsdx.mi', 'xdbc.mi', 'xssx.mi', 'djlev.mi', 'leonia.mi', 'pef.mi', 'peh.mi', 'pwd.mi', 'pwc.mi', 'pft.mi', 'xgle.mi', 'x13e.mi', 
'xtxc.mi', 'x35e.mi', 'x57e.mi', 'xeon.mi', 'xein.mi', 'x710.mi', 'xgin.mi', 'x15e.mi', 'x25e.mi', 'iukp.mi', 'ih2o.mi', 'br50.mi', 'xsps.mi', 'xmrc.mi', 
'xfvt.mi', 'xlpe.mi', 'xsgi.mi', 'xxsc.mi', 'xaus.mi', 'xsfr.mi', 'levmib.mi', 'bermib.mi', 'xbrmib.mi', 'xtc5.mi', 'xffe.mi', 'xstr.mi', 'ener.mi', 'wat.mi', 
'exs1.mi', 'exxy.mi', 'exhe.mi', 'exsi.mi', 'exsa.mi', 'exx5.mi', 'exsh.mi', 'imib.mi', 'inrg.mi', 'imeu.mi', 'ltam.mi', 'xsgl.mi', 'xemb.mi', 'peu.mi', 'auco.mi', 
'rtwo.mi', 'xgsh.mi', 'bxx.mi', 'xesc.mi', 'xaxj.mi', 'xpxj.mi', 'xsx6.mi', 'xcac.mi', 'icov.mi', 'exvm.mi', 'xldx.mi', 'xs2l.mi', 'ieag.mi', 'ieac.mi', 'iege.mi', 
'csbgu7.mi', 'csbgu3.mi', 'csbge7.mi', 'csbge3.mi', 'csemus.mi', 'csuss.mi', 'sema.mi', 'sjpa.mi', 'smea.mi', 'se15.mi', 'sega.mi', 'ibgz.mi', 'ibgy.mi', 
'spxj.mi', 'swda.mi', 'del2.mi', 'des2.mi', 'c5l.mi', 'cl2.mi', 'cl1.mi', 'c5s.mi', 'c2u.mi', 'cssx5e.mi', 'csndx.mi', 'csmib.mi', 'csnky.mi', 'cspxj.mi', 
'csca.mi', 'csuk.mi', 'csus.mi', 'csjp.mi', 'csemu.mi', 'cb5.mi', 'ch5.mi', 'xsd2.mi', 'xt21.mi', 'ci3.mi', 'cu9.mi', 'cm9.mi', 'sb0.mi', 's10.mi', 'csspx.mi', 
'e50eua.mi', 'emueua.mi', 'emveua.mi', 'eureua.mi', 'jpneua.mi', 'paceua.mi', 'usaeua.mi', 'wrdeua.mi', 'caneua.mi', 'xblc.mi', 'comf.mi', 'spx.mi', 'aust.mi', 
'can.mi', 'dax2s.mi', 'bund2s.mi', 'c13.mi', 'c33.mi', 'c53.mi', 'c73.mi', 'c10.mi', 'c3m.mi', 'cg1.mi', 'xspx.mi', 'xmex.mi', 'xcan.mi', 'xder.mi', 'csru.mi', 
'csmxcp.mi', 'cskr.mi', 'csemas.mi', 'iemb.mi', 'telew.mi', 'disw.mi', 'staw.mi', 'indgw.mi', 'tnow.mi', 'utiw.mi', 'enerw.mi', 'matw.mi', 'hltw.mi', 'finsw.mi', 
'ihyg.mi', 'xb4f.mi', 'xy4p.mi', 'xbtr.mi', 'xb13.mi', 'xmin.mi', 'ijpe.mi', 'iwde.mi', 'iuse.mi', 'xcs4.mi', 'btp2s.mi', 'btp2l.mi', 'bund2l.mi', 'eumv.mi', 
's6ew.mi', 'spmv.mi', 'esm.mi', 'seml.mi', 'cs1.mi', 'cu1.mi', 'xgvd.mi', 'xbot.mi', 'emmv.mi', 'emld.mi', 'euco.mi', 'govy.mi', 'acwe.mi', 'imie.mi', 'emae.mi', 
'emrg.mi', 'emdv.mi', 'usdv.mi', 'jnke.mi', 'spy5.mi', 'eudv.mi', 'govs.mi', 'xmk9.mi', 'iitb.mi', 'xcha.mi', 'womv.mi', '100eua.mi', 'emmeua.mi', 'wsreua.mi', 
'asreua.mi', 'esreua.mi', 'psreua.mi', 'ut1eua.mi', 'ut7eua.mi', 'gs1eua.mi', 'ecoeua.mi', 'emgeas.mi', 'ajeuas.mi', 'usaeuy.mi', 'usveuy.mi', 'sp5euy.mi', 
'bsx.mi', 'xliq.mi', 'xd5e.mi', 'lvo.mi', 'xdjp.mi', 'cceuas.mi', 'euro.mi', 'glre.mi', 'lowv.mi', 'iexf.mi', 'ihyu.mi', 'emcr.mi', 'corp.mi', 'jpnh.mi', 
'spxh.mi', 'crwe.mi', 'sf5eua.mi', 'sf1eua.mi', 'xqui.mi', 'xcs2.mi', 'xg7s.mi', 'xgiu.mi', 'xyp1.mi', 'useuwh.mi', 'ukeubh.mi', 'jpeubh.mi', 'ircp.mi', 'sdhy.mi', 
'erne.mi', 's2eubh.mi', 'sw2chb.mi', 'xjse.mi', 'mlps.mi', 'mlpd.mi', 'rqfi.mi', 'pjs1.mi', 'sthe.mi', 'ss1eua.mi', 'seuc.mi', 'snkk.mi', 'gldv.mi', 'padv.mi', 
'susc.mi', 'spy4.mi', 'saus.mi', 'emlc.mi', 'xbag.mi', 'xbae.mi', 'itamid.mi', 'cash.mi', 'cbeu5.mi', 'cbuse.mi', 'isjp.mi', 'psrw.mi', 'buyb.mi', 'cape.mi', 
'xdax.mi', 'xmaw.mi', 'xd9u.mi', 'eimi.mi', 'emul.mi', 'chna.mi', 'sdje50.mi', 'x7ps.mi', 'efiw.mi', 'mxfs.mi', 'smseur.mi', 'smsjpn.mi', 'smswld.mi', 'rdxs.mi',
'sr2000.mi', 'spxs.mi', 'sdj600.mi', 'xlys.mi', 'xlps.mi', 'xles.mi', 'xlfs.mi', 'xlvs.mi', 'xlis.mi', 'xlbs.mi', 'xlks.mi', 'xlus.mi', 'xs7w.mi', 'xdwd.mi', 
'mlpi.mi', 'gldvd.mi', 'dsus.mi', 'strx.mi', 'stsx.mi', 'stnx.mi', 'stzx.mi', 'stwx.mi', 'stqx.mi', 'stpx.mi', 'smcx.mi','stkx.mi', 'erox.mi', 'stux.mi', 
'r2us.mi', 'elow.mi', 'mint.mi', 'emli.mi', 'dem.mi', 'dgse.mi', 'eei.mi', 'dfe.mi', 'dhs.mi', 'dese.mi', 'dxj.mi', 'robo.mi', 'cbus5.mi', 'cbus.mi', 'caheua.mi', 
'sthy.mi', 'iwqu.mi', 'iwmo.mi', 'iwvl.mi', 'iwsz.mi', 'iequ.mi', 'iemo.mi', 'ievl.mi', 'iesz.mi', 'mvol.mi', 'mvus.mi', 'emv.mi', 'mveu.mi', 'xhy1.mi', 
'xhyg.mi', 'xrsm.mi', 'xdpe.mi', 'xrs2.mi', 'hdlv.mi', 'ccusas.mi', 'conv.mi', 'cbus5e.mi', 'spvx.mi', 'hybb.mi', 'smart.mi', 'hedj.mi', 'srsa.mi', 'fedf.mi', 
'cbsus.mi', 'hyld.mi', 'embe.mi', 'iebb.mi', 'cgb.mi', 'xdeb.mi', 'elovd.mi', 'xdem.mi', 'xdeq.mi', 'xdev.mi', 'epvld.mi', 'eqltd.mi', 'etsyd.mi', 'ulovd.mi', 
'uqltd.mi', 'upvld.mi', 'capu.mi', 'dema.mi', 'mfdd.mi', 'usig.mi', 'auheua.mi', 'meud.mi', 'ispy.mi', 'dxgy.mi', 'hedf.mi', 'dxjf.mi', 'dxjz.mi', 'acwie.mi', 
'ulove.mi', 'uqlte.mi', 'bbeu.mi', 'exs3.mi', 'sxly.mi', 'sxlp.mi', 'sxle.mi', 'sxlf.mi', 'sxlv', 'sxli.mi', 'sxlb.mi', 'sxlk.mi', 'sxli.mi', 'sxlb.mi', 'sxlk.mi', 
'sxlu.mi', 'emh5.mi', 'trs3.mi', 'trsy.mi', 'tips.mi', 'eure.mi', 'jpeh.mi', 'cnaa.mi', 'sbem.mi', 'xweh.mi', 'xdny.mi', 'xdne.mi', 'xdgu.mi', 'ust1f.mi', 
'smartu.mi', 'spx2s.mi', 'efie.mi', 'euhd.mi', 'jpmv.mi', 'xdwh.mi', 'xdwf.mi', 'xdw0.mi', 'xdws.mi', 'xdwc.mi', 'xdwu.mi', 'xwts.mi', 'xdwm.mi', 'xdwm.mi', 
'xdwt.mi', 'xdwi.mi', 'bot6m.mi', 'lafri.mi', 'hyfa.mi', 'ifsw.mi', 'ifse.mi', 'ifsu.mi', 'emdh.mi', 'sbeme.mi', 'ecdb.mi', 'ecbc.mi', 'wcoa.mi', 'dgra.mi', 
'ggra.mi', 'egra.mi', 'usih.mi', 'ushy.mi', 'em57.mi', 'em15.mi', 'em710.mi', 'emaaa.mi', 'xdge.mi', 'xqua.mi', 'xdep.mi', 'cbsuse.mi', 'msrusa.mi', 'jpsre.mi', 
'jpsr.mi', 'ussrf.mi', 'n400.mi', 'ldce.mi', 'ldcu.mi', 'dfea.mi', 'demr.mi', 'eeia.mi', 'dhsa.mi', 'chin.mi', 'us37.mi', 'us13.mi', 'aged.mi', 'rbot.mi', 
'dgtl.mi', 'heal.mi', 'wing.mi', 'dhsf.mi', 'wldx.mi', 'usyh.mi', 'tip10d.mi', 'tip1d.mi', 'ust10f.mi', 'tip1e.mi', 'usco.mi', 'eu35.mi', 'trs5.mi', 'lutr.mi', 
'eu7l.mi', 'lgov.mi', 'iucb.mi', 'lusc.mi', 'crba.mi', 'cbseu.mi', 'brz.mi', 'bund19.mi', 'btp1s.mi', 'u13h.mi', 'mvaw.mi', 'mvae.mi', 'mvam.mi', 'infu.mi', 
'tipu.mi', 'epie.mi', 'ceu2.mi', 'ggov.mi', 'nram.mi', 'mwrd.mi', 's500.mi', 'ecrp.mi', 'egov.mi', 'epra.mi', 'gagg.mi', 'ebbb.mi', 'ubbb.mi', 'atip.mi', 
'pqvm.mi', 'xute.mi', 'xmvu.mi', 'xmve.mi', 'unca.mi', 'hmem.mi', 'hmjd.mi', 'hspd.mi', 'hmwd.mi', 'h50e.mi', 'cmod.mi', 'ceud.mi', 'gdx.mi', 'gdxj.mi', 
'moat.mi', 'eueua.mi', 'eea.mi', 'eemk.mi', 'eemu.mi', 'eeue.mi', 'enam.mi', 'epej.mi', 'evoe.mi', 'evou.mi', 'emom.mi', 'equa.mi', 'evae.mi', 'ejah.mi', 
'eeng.mi', 'itapir.mi', 'smtu.mi', 'usfmd.mi', 'cbusih.mi', 'hap.mi', 'gdig.mi', 'hys.mi', 'histh.mi', 'floth.mi', 'jels.mi', 'jpmf.mi', 'jpst.mi', 'jpmb.mi', 
'flxg.mi', 'flxe.mi', 'flxd.mi', 'flxx.mi', 'flxu.mi', 'pref.mi', 'infl.mi', 'msed.mi', 'ipir.mi', 'val.mi', 'mms.mi', 'gwt.mi', 'btp10.mi', 'btp13', 'xmme.mi', 
'xque.mi', 'xutd.mi', 'xgii.mi', 'prfd.mi', 'floe.mi', 'fltr.mi', 'awsrie.mi', 'batt.mi', 'ecom.mi', 'biot.mi', 'ekus.mi', 'eisr.mi', 'infl1.mi', 'infl10.mi', 
'shemb.mi', 'sdjsmi.ml', 'spxd.mi', 'sdje5d.mi', 'mvau.mi', 'fts100', 'glag.mi', 'glae.mi', 'je13.mi', 'em13.mi', 'em35.mi', 'em1015.mi', 'emg.mi', 'emi.mi', 
'puig.mi', 'psfe.mi', 'pemd.mi', 'emu.mi', 'mktn.mi', 'gendee.mi', 'sheme.mi', 'glux.mi', 'cwe.mi', 'cwf.mi', 'epre.mi', 'fmi.mi', 'b500.mi', 'c40.mi', 'c50.mi', 
'cmu.mi', 'cj1.mi', 'cp9.mi', 'lwcr.mi', 'smrt.mi', 'gfa.mi', 'hyem.mi', 'us3.mi', 'us7.mi', 'us1.mi', 'ageb.mi', 'afin.mi', 'cbbb.mi', 'am3a.mi', 'axfi.mi', 
'aa13.mi', 'gcve.mi', 'lcwd.mi', 'lcus.mi', 'lcuk.mi', 'lcjp.mi', 'lcas.mi', 'xuhy.mi', 'xyld.mi', 'xcs6.mi', 'emqq.mi', 'skyy.mi', '500h.mi', 'mceu.mi', 
'a500.mi', 'rs2k.mi', 'qceu.mi', 'cn1.mi', 'ceu.mi', 'alat.mi', 'aasi.mi', 'jpnk.mi', 'jphe.mi', 'putw.mi', 'ccbo.mi', 'cb3.mi', 'x1g.mi', 'x13g.mi', 'usfrn.mi', 
'hhfrn.mi', 'cc4.mi', 'ahye.mi', 'afrn.mi', 'emuaa.mi', 'usmufe.mi', 'cw8.mi', 'ndxh.mi', 'ci2.mi', 'cc1.mi', 'aeem.mi', 'tpxh.mi', 'mivo.mi', 'vceu.mi', 'anx.mi', 
'cu2.mi', 'iqee.mi', 'iqmu. mi', 'iqjp.mi', 'iqec.mi', 'iqeg.mi', 'flqa.mi', 'fleq.mi', 'fluc.mi', 'fles.mi', 'prfe.mi', 'bbeg.mi', 'hqla1.mi', 'blok.mi', 
'ucrp.mi', 'eufm.mi', 'ufle.mi', 'efnt.mi', 'at1.mi', 'xat1.mi', 'jree.mi', 'jrem.mi', 'jreg.mi', 'jreu.mi', 'jlse.mi', 'jmfe.mi', 'jest.mi', 'ju13.mi', 'xzw0.mi', 
'xzeu.mi', 'xzmj.mi', 'xzmu.mi', 'emloc.mi', 'cmoe.mi', 'xuem.mi', 'yld.mi', 'eyld.mi', 'gove.mi', 'wgov.mi', 'bnku.mi', 'dfj.mi', 'dfja.mi', 'usmf.mi', 'fctr.mi', 
'sxlc.mi', 'efim.mi', 'xlcs.mi', 'jmbe.mi', 'eacw.mi', 'cobo.mi', 'wcoe.mi', 'roai.mi', 'mdbe.mi', 'wesg.mi', 'uesg.mi', 'eesg.mi', 'mesg.mi', 'feuz.mi', 
'at1d.mi', 'e500.mi', 'sbio.mi', 'uflt.mi', 'eqeu.mi', 'itek.mi', 'lgus.mi', 'lggl.mi', 'lgjp.mi', 'lgeu.mi', 'lgap.mi', 'vrps.mi', 'teet.mi', 'tget.mi', 
'tret.mi', 'tat.mi', 'tcbt.mi', 'tgbt.mi', 'tdiv.mi', 'tnae.mi', 'tswe.mi', 'goai.mi', 'wsri.mi', 'usri.mi', 'eusri.mi', 'swrd.mi', 'jreb.mi', 'jr15.mi', 
'jrub.mi', 'vapx.mi', 'vwrl.mi', 'vfem.mi', 'vusa.mi', 'vuke.mi', 'vhyl.mi', 'veur.mi', 'vjpn.mi', 'vusc.mi', 'veve.mi', 'vmom.mi', 'vval.mi', 'vmvl.mi', 
'vliq.mi', 'vecp.mi', 'vety.mi', 'vucp.mi', 'vemt.mi', 'vuty.mi', 'icfp.mi', 'acwia.mi', 'flot.mi', 'us10.mi', 'u10h.mi', 'cbef.mi', 'crpe.mi', 'hy.mi', 
'emktb.mi', 'embh.mi', 'spxe.mi', 'tres.mi', 'tre3.mi', 'tre7.mi', 'trex.mi', 'hmch.mi', 'htwn.mi', 'hmyd.mi', 'hkor.mi', 'hidd.mi', 'hmla.mi', 'hzar.mi', 
'hhmeu.mi', 'hprd.mi', 'hrub.mi', 'hmfe.mi', 'hmxj.mi', 'hmaf.mi', 'hmca.mi', 'hwwa.mi', 'aaa57.mi', 'aaa13.mi', 'aaa35.mi', 'rewld.mi', 'bnke.mi', 'acwi.mi', 
'wtai.mi', 'uine.mi', 'linf.mi', 'usausw.mi', 'ukgbpb.mi', 'cana.mi', 'emmusc.mi', 'reeu.mi', 'reusa.mi', 'pvx.mi', 'sel.mi', 'kuw8.mi', 'mdba.mi', '5hee.mi', 
'owle.mi', 'ausauw.mi', 'wnrg.mi', 'wfin.mi', 'whea.mi', 'wtec.mi', 'jpna.mi', 'xres.mi', 'bbus.mi', 'bbud.mi', 'ust.mi', 'bnk.mi', 'bres.mi', 'foo.mi', 'hlt.mi', 
'oil.mi', 'tno.mi', 'tele.mi', 'uti.mi', 'etfeu.mi', 'etfez.mi', 'etfglo.mi', 'etfjap.mi', 'etfusa.mi', 'etfcor.mi', 'etfgov.mi', 'etfgg.mi', 'etfust.mi', 
'esee.mi', 'eseh.mi', 'lceu.mi', 'jbem.mi', 'srie.mi', 'srij.mi', 'sric.mi', 'autp.mi', 'chm.mi', 'cst.mi', 'fins.mi', 'indg.mi', 'ins.mi', 'mda.mi', 'phg.mi', 
'rta.mi', 'trvl.mi', 'bbtr.mi', 'flrg.mi', 'flxb.mi', 'flxc.mi', 'flxi.mi', 'flxk.mi', 'emsri.mi', 'bchn.mi', 'trxe.mi', 'cina.mi', 'crbn.mi', 'crb.mi', 'hk.mi', 
'apex.mi', 'aej.mi', 'kor.mi', 'twn.mi', '5esge.mi', 'afrn7.mi', 'esge.mi', 'crbh.mi', 'bra.mi', 'est.mi', 'latam.mi', 'mal.mi', 'rus.mi', 'safri.mi', 'tur.mi', 
'indo.mi', 'tai.mi', 'well.mi', 'spesg.mi', 'gended.mi', 'reuse.mi', 'jpsa.mi', 'esgw.mi', 'esgu.mi', 'esgx.mi', 'emige.mi', 'emig.mi', 'emhe.mi', 'e50esg.mi', 
'cinesg.mi', 'aiai.mi', 'glug.mi', 'doct.mi', 'oufe.mi', 'suoe.mi', 'suse.mi', 'iese.mi', 'aggh.mi', 'lock.mi', 'ecar.mi', 'susm.mi', 'suas.mi', 'susw.mi', 
'sujp.mi', 'espo.mi', 'mxus.mi', 'bbil.mi', 'clim.mi', 'gist.mi', 'iqsa.mi', 'jpgl.mi', 'jpus.mi', 'rieu.mi', 'eibb.mi', 'eib3.mi', 'eib5.mi', 'eib7.mi', 
'eibx.mi', '600x.mi', 'cbsusa.mi', 'msrusb.mi', 'emusri.mi', 'wsrus.mi', 'lccn.mi', 'emxc.mi', 'flte.mi', 'stpe.mi', 'fltu.mi', 'stpu.mi', 'sric3.mi', 'sric5.mi', 
'musri.mi', 'greal.mi', 'etfusc.mi', 'ecrp3.mi', 'wcld.mi', 'hmsa.mi', 'ego.mi', 'eqac.mi', '500x.mi', 'mxud.mi', 'rius.mi', 'emde.mi', 'scity.mi', 'binfu.mi', 
'smafy.mi', 'jmba.mi', 'mtig.mi', 'eesm.mi', 'gsce.mi', 'emwe.mi', 'gslc.mi', 'gsem.mi', 'cbnd.mi', 'awsria.mi', 'wldh.mi', 'trei.mi', 'iqse.mi', 'vgea.mi', 
'vdca.mi', 'vuce.mi', 'veca.mi', 'vdea.mi', 'vwce.mi', 'vwcg.mi', 'vere.mi', 'vjpa.mi', 'vhve.mi', 'vfea.mi', 'vagf.mi', 'vdta.mi', 'vuaa.mi', 'volt.mi', 
'uhys.mi', 'ehys.mi', 'ghye.mi', 'jghy.mi', 'usesg.mi', 'wdesg.mi', 'cmxus.mi', 'wdesge.mi', 'bund1s.mi', 'cybr.mi', 'jjt13.mi', 'cib.mi', 'ege.mi', 'fsky.mi', 
'ussri.mi', 'ussrie.mi', 'wsria.mi', 'wsrie.mi', 'unic.mi', 'mill.mi', 'ebuy.mi', 'elcr.mi', 'iqct.mi', 'uhysh.mi', 'ghyeh.mi', 'usde.mi', 'tip10e.mi', 'usrih.mi', 
'spmv.mi', '5esg.mi', 'sawd.mi', 'city.mi', 'suou.mi', 'cnyb.mi', 'e127.mi', 'greit.mi', 'uussmc.mi', 'fbt.mi', 'cibr.mi', 'eco.mi', 'govg.mi'
```

Tnx in advance for every suggestion about how to solve my downloading issue.

Comment: As far as the *minimal* part of [mcve], it will be easier for folks to help you, and much less of a strain on us, if you can narrow that list down to a subset of tickers where the issue occurs and doesn't occur. I wouldn't assume people here want to run all 1000, and it's good debugging practice

Comment: sure, the tickers set is made of about 77 rows. The issue arises when I try to download more than 20 rows of symbols.  I don't know yet from which exact number of requests the yahoo server starts to trash my query.  I was wondering if there is some command (Sys.sleep() maybe) in order to slow down my requests flow. Please note that in the past I have downloaded the quotes by putting ALL the tickers name in '''

Comment: '''tickers = c() '''.  You haven't to try all the combinations in order to reproduce the error. Simply You have to copy-paste the tickers list in ''' tickers = c()'''

Comment: Right, but it's good debugging practice for you to first figure out a subset of tickers for us that recreate the issue, instead of us trying to figure it out. But a pause in between queries definitely sounds like a good thing to try

Comment: Ok, I'll try to split the download in 4 step and then merge the chunks. I'll let You now if it works

Comment: My script works when I split the tickers in four chunks, but I have to run it step by step becouse I noticed the response time of yahoo server changes in a random fashion from 180 seconds to over 300.  It's a pity becouse some months ago worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

yahoo is used time to time to modify the query strings ... avoid your "meat" is free that much ..! :-)

How did you get the list of such etf ?

you can try with:

```
import yfinance as yf
etf = ['eue.mi', 'eun.mi', 'mse.mi', 'dje.mi', 'iusa.mi', 'eqqq.mi', 'mgt.mi] # you can put the whole bunch of etf in a single list..yf will retrive those at once 
tit = yf.download(tickers=etf, period='max')
```

except those delisted, to me worked fine

Comment: This seems to be python rather than R.

Comment: yes it is .. you can try convert it in R since I don't have specifications

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31082803)